# restricting application stored data access in disk using Linux user permissions

Tags: java, linux, permissions, file-permissions

I'm developing a Java SE application that will run on Linux. 
The application stores some files and directories on disk.

I need only the application itself be able to read/write these files/directories (i.e. the current logged in user shouldn't be able to read/write/copy these files using OS File Manager).
I tried to create a user and a usergroup and change permissions of files to 600 and directories to 700.
The problem is application runs as current logged in user so it stores files with current user as owner.
If I do `chown` on the files then application can't read files anymore!

What should I do to restrict files/directories access to an application?

Answer (score 1):

I think `setuid` is your choice. See man page for details. Here is the [wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), also a good reference.

Each program has a `uid/gid` and `euid/egid`, you should have its `euid/egid` match the file access permission.

---

In detail, IIRC, you should run your Java SE program like `java mainclass` or `java -jar main.jar`. Write the startup command in a script, e.g. `run.sh`.

FILE BEGIN run.sh

```
java mainclass # or java -jar main.jar choose one appropriate to you
```

FILE END

and then `sudo chown root run.sh` and then `sudo chmod ug+s run.sh`.

This assumes you are in the sudoer list. If not, you have to turn to an SA for help.

Comment: Thanks but how can I change `euid/egid` of a J2SE application?

Comment: @4r1y4n How will you release your program? A `jar` file? I think you can wrap it with a startup script. And `setuid` on the script. Hope that help :).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried your solution; But still I am [current user] and can't read roots files !! I made a `run.sh` and wrote the `java -jar ...` in it. then changed owner to root and set `SetGid` and `SetUid` flags. then ran `run.sh` and I'm still [current user] (as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"whoami"})` reports )!

Comment: This may be because some shell interpreter omit the `setuid` bit on scripts for some potential security problems. I find this post after googling, and I think this may give you some hint to your problem. Here is the URL http://www.coderanch.com/t/110254/Linux-UNIX/setuid

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible. There is no distinction in permissions between a user and the programs that they run.